# LINQ left outer join , Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: linq, join

I am trying to perform left outer join on 2 data tables and getting an error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
My Code is :

```
    var result =
                                from dataRows1 in dtInv.AsEnumerable()
                                join dataRows2 in dtSal.AsEnumerable()
                                on dataRows1.Field<string>("taken_by").ToUpper() == null ? "" : dataRows1.Field<string>("taken_by").ToUpper()
                                equals dataRows2.Field<string>("taken_by").ToUpper() == null ? "" : dataRows2.Field<string>("taken_by").ToUpper() into lj
                                from r in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
                            {
                                dataRows1.Field<string>("taken_by") == null ? "": dataRows1.Field<string>("taken_by"),
                                dataRows1.Field<int>("TotalInv") == null ? 0 : dataRows1.Field<int>("TotalInv"),
                                dataRows1.Field<double>("TotalAmt") == null ? 0.00 : dataRows1.Field<double>("TotalAmt"),
                                r == null ? 0 : r.Field<int>("TotalSal"),
                                r == null ? 0 : r.Field<double>("SalAmt")
                            }, false);
```

Comment: Perhaps some "taken_by" values are null and the exception is thrown when you try to run ToUpper?

Comment: thanks for your help, it is working now.